# Where can I ask about the subject 'advertising on chromecast'

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The question:

> What Ad-Providers provide adverts designed for transmission over
>   Chromecast (the issue being that clicks are not likely to be registered ever - much like you don't get clicks from a television).

The issue is that this is very likely to lead to a opinion / find me library close vote on Stack Overflow.

Is there an SE site that would better suit this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is likely to be closed on any SE site as being too broad.

This question is likely to result in a set of list answers, and questions of this type don't tend to work on SE because they don't have an objectively correct answer - any number of answers or none at all can be correct.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought that would likely be the result.

Answer (score 3):

I think not, since the subject itself is not fit for the SE model in general, for the same reasons it doesn't fit on Stack Overflow.

All subjective, list-of-things questions don't do well here. Maybe there are some forums on Chromecast you could use for your question.

Comment: Thank you, I thought as much. I'll find a different avenue of research.